# Оптимизация фрагмента кода

Tags: алгоритм, мк-61

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать данный фрагмент кода в плане его длины:

```
ИП1 П8
1 П0
  4 П7
    0 П9 1 ПA
    ИП8 1 6 / [x] ПB 1 6 * ИП8 - /-/ С/П
    ИПA * ИП9 + П9 ИПA 1 6 * ПA ИПB П8
  ИП7 1 - П7 x=0 10
ИП0 x#0 52 0 П0 ИП9 П1 ИП2 П8 БП 04
ИП8 П2
```

Его смысл следующий: в регистрах Р1 и Р2 лежит число (Р1 - младшие разряды, Р2 - старшие). В ходе выполнения программы на экран выводится каждый 16-чный разряд этого числа, после вывода которого она принимает с клавиатуры такие же 16-чные значения. Из них составляется новое число, помещаемое в эти же регистры, т. е. осуществляется замена разрядов. В каждый регистр помещается по два байта числа (по четыре 16-чных разряда). Регистры с 3 по 6 заняты.

Comment: @Русский, а почему используете МК-61? Just for fun?

Comment: С давних пор имеется. Написание программ под него мне представляется своеобразной тренировкой ума для русского программиста. Это с одной стороны. С другой - он всё-таки довольно удобен как вычислительное средство, программирующееся, так сказать, на ходу, даже несмотря на скорость работы.

Comment: (Оффтопик) Круто было бы написать для него оптимизирующий компилятор. Неблагодарное это, все же, дело, руками анализировать логические выражения, да раскладывать по регистрам. На это все алгоритмы придуманы.

Comment: >как можно оптимизировать данный фрагмент

####О__о HOLY MOTHER OF GOD

Comment: @Русский, я какое-то время назад пробовал что-то на нем посчитать, но оказалось что я уже слишком избалован мгновенными ответами от современных компьютеров, ждать 15-30, а то и боле секунд, пока завершится простенькая программа, для меня это уже слишком:)

@Spectre, это всего лишь вариация на тему стековой машины, ничего страшного там нет)

@Русский, а об МК-161, МК-152 не слышали? Они, правда, не поддерживают недокументированных возможностей и прочей [еггогологии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) старых калькуляторов.

Comment: Я полагаю, компилятор не сможет превзойти пытливый ум советского программиста, сумевшего уложиться в предоставленные ресурсы этой машины при создании таких программ, что становится трудным даже представить, как это стало возможным.

Насчёт МК-161/152 на китайских микросхемах по $100 за штуку, конечно, слышал. Правда, что от них толку, я так и не сообразил: к отечественному компьютеростроению это относится лишь косвенно, а запросы потребителей с такими ценами они врядли удовлетворят.

Comment: Я полагаю, пытливый ум занимается тем же, что и оптимизатор компилятора — минимизирует граф потока управления. Чудес не бывает, бывает только что компилятор не знает каких-либо приемов.

Comment: Согласен, но о том я и пишу: заставить компилятор выполнять ту же работу, что делали советские программисты, в теории, конечно, возможно, но вот на практике - по крайней мере, очень и очень сложно. Хотя, конечно, иметь такой компилятор было бы прекрасно. Я вот думал написать хотя бы среду разработки для этого дела, да всё времени не хватает.

Comment: По поводу оптимизации, возможно получится избавиться от одного из вспомогательных регистров (возможно даже от обоих), если сохранять значение в стеке, и возможно программа укоротится на одну команду. В прошлой программе я пробовал так сделать, но получилось так на так: -2 команды записи-чтения регистра +2 команды B-вверх. Единственный плюс, что регистр освободился.

Comment: > Круто было бы написать для него оптимизирующий компилятор.

Это имело бы смысл, если бы компилятор можно было реализовать средствами МК-61 ;) А писать программу на PC для компиляции программы в код МК-61 - это, простите, извращение)

Comment: Про вспомогательный регистр согласен: как минимум, он освободится для записи постоянных, используемых программой. Я так понял, что вы про регистр РB. А вторым вспомогательным Вы имели в виду какой? Назначение у них такое: 1 и 2 - число, 7 и 0 - счётчики, 8 - поступающее в цикл для обработки значение, 9 - результат этой обработки, A - множитель, степень 16, B - новое значение для регистра 8.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что придумалось - это применить команду L0 для организации цикла с четырьмя итерациями:

```
ИП1 П8
1 П7
  5 П0
    - || -
  L0 10
ИП7 x#0 48 0 П7 ИП9 П1 ИП2 П8 БП 04
ИП9 П2
```

Но этого, к сожалению, мало: код занимает целых 50 команд.

Comment: На некотором алгоритмическом языке это можно выразить так:

    знач := мл_часть;
    флаг := 1;
    Метка_1:
    сч := 5;
    рез := 0;
    множ := 1;
    Метка_2:
    буфер := ЦЕЛЧАСТЬ(знач / 16);
    X := - (буфер * 16 - знач);
    ОСТАНОВ; // X на экране
    X := ПРИЁМ();
    рез := X * множ + рез;
    множ := множ * 16;
    знач := буфер;
    ЕСЛИ сч # 1 ТО ПЕРЕХОД Метка_2 КОН; УМЕНЬШИТЬ(сч);
    ЕСЛИ флаг = 0 ТО ПЕРЕХОД Метка_3 ИНАЧЕ
      флаг := 0;
      мл_часть := рез;
      знач := ст_часть;
      ПЕРЕХОД Метка_1
    КОН;
    Метка_3:
    ст_часть := рез